# Add Laos Font to SharePoint 2013 or New font to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Now I have a SharePoint website. I need to add a new font to improve my website's look but I don't know how to apply that step. Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Font-squirrel generator. It creates a package which you can import into your SharePoint site. I chose to create a font folder within the Style Library.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Then you can reference everything in your style.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'writehandregular';
  src: url('/Style%20Library/Fonts/writehand.eot');
  src: url('/Style%20Library/Fonts/writehand.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/Style%20Library/Fonts/writehand.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/Style%20Library/Fonts/writehand.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/Style%20Library/Fonts/writehand.svg#writehandregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}
```

Now you can use the font family anywhere (that imports style.css):

```
<div style='font-family:writehandregular'>This is a custom font!</div>
```